# Mysql "OR" query fetch rows in order of conditions

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (condition 1) OR (condition 2) OR (condition3)
```

Can I make this query show the rows from condition 1, followed by the ones from condition2 and finally condition 3?

I did this by using UNION and it worked, but it's slower (tested the query on my mysql) - actually it's faster than the "OR" query if there are no duplicates but way slower if there are.

Ty!

Comment: Try using CASE in ORDER BY clause

Comment: You can ORDER BY Condition1 and/or use CASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (condition 1) OR (condition 2) OR (condition3)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN condition=1 THEN 1 
         CASE WHEN condition=2 THEN 2
         CASE WHEN condition=3 THEN 3
         END
```

Comment: Very interesting, ty! I will test it to see if it's faster than the union query

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `UNION ALL`, as you did. To avoid duplicates, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (condition 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (condition 2) AND NOT (condition 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (condition 3) AND NOT (condition 1 OR condition 2)
```

But it's probably still gonna be  slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ORDER BY` to achieve this.
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (condition 1) OR (condition 2) OR (condition3)
ORDER BY ((condition 1) * 4 + (condition 2) * 2 + condition 1) DESC;
```

Edit:
In fact, you are basically building a 3-bit number and sorting with it.
Imagine this *truth table*:

```
 C1 | C2  | C3  | Result
  0 |   0 |   0 |    0
  0 |   0 |   1 |    1
  0 |   1 |   0 |    2
  0 |   1 |   1 |    3
  1 |   0 |   0 |    4
  1 |   0 |   1 |    5
  1 |   1 |   0 |    6
  1 |   1 |   1 |    7
```

If you sort by `result DESC` (from bottom to top), you are in fact sorting first by C1, then if false, by C2, then if false, by C3.

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you give me a mysql reference?

Comment: See my edit, that's not MySQL dependant, that's binary string manipulation.